# PostgreSQL - Loop seems to have gone asynchronous for a bit

Tags: postgresql

I have table1 that is obsolete and is being replaced by table2. My goal was to move all the records in table1 to table2. In order to avoid id collisions when moving the data, I ran this function which just goes through updating the table1.ids if a matching table2.id already exists:

```
DO
$do$
DECLARE
    row RECORD;
BEGIN
  FOR row IN
    SELECT t1.id, t1.name, t2.id, t2.name
    FROM sch.table1 AS t1
    JOIN sch.table2 AS t2
    ON t1.id = t2.id
  LOOP
    UPDATE sch.table1
      SET id = (select greatest(
        (select max(id) from sch.table1),
        (select max(id) from sch.table2)) + 1)
      WHERE id = row.id;
    -- more code here that updates tables with table1.id as foreign key
  END LOOP;
END
$do$;
```

For the most part that function worked as was intended, with over 100 records being sorted out correctly. Oddly enough though, it seems as if it ran asynchronously for just a tiny bit. Before the function ran, I had these 8 records in table1 (I've edited the names):

```
id  |name
----|-----------------------------
450 |Number Zero
451 |Number One
452 |Number Two
453 |Number Three
454 |Number Four
455 |Number Five
456 |Number Six
457 |Number Seven
```

After the function ran those 8 records were:

```
id  |name
----|-----------------------------
1138|Number Zero
1139|Number One
1139|Number Two
1140|Number Three
1140|Number Four
1141|Number Five
1141|Number Six
1142|Number Seven
```

Every record before "Number One" and after "Number Six" was updated accordingly. The strange thing is that 6 records were paired up. Two records were assigned the id 1139, 1140 and 1141. I have no idea how this happened and I need to know in order to find a way to avoid this!

Any ideas?

PS. I ran the SQL code on DataGrip, and the PostgreSQL DB is located on AWS. Just stating this in case any of it is important.

Comment: What if you 'commit' after each update, before the next iteration?

Comment: @varontron I will try that first thing tomorrow.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're fetching from a table which you're updating and the fetch (join) is based on a column which you're updating which is probably the primary key. Postgres must not select all rows before it is entering the loop.

In your code are some other issues, too:

1. What should be the value of `row.id`; `t1.id` or `t2.id`? You should use explicit alias names for the `id` and `name` columns.
2. In the relational model and in SQL, relations (tables) have no specific order. You should use an explicit `ORDER BY` clause. It's a coincidence if the lines are numbered as you want them to be.
3. The maximal value for `id` of `t2` is an invariant of the loop. So you can compute the maximum outside of the loop into a variable and increase the value of this variable inside of the loop.
4. I don't see any reason for the join in the loop, since you don't seem to be using the values of `table2`. So you may omit the join.

Putting all together, you should try something like:

```
DO
$do$
DECLARE
    row RECORD;
    i INTEGER;
BEGIN
  i := greatest(
        (select max(id) from sch.table1),
        (select max(id) from sch.table2)) + 1;
  FOR row IN
    SELECT t1.id, t1.name FROM sch.table1 AS t1 ORDER BY ...
  LOOP
    UPDATE sch.table1 SET id = i WHERE id = row.id;
    i := i + 1;
  END LOOP;
END
$do$;
```

But there is always the problem that you're updating the primary key of `table1`. If this code doesn't work you should save the primary key in a temporary column:

```
ALTER TABLE table1 ADD old_id INTEGER;
UPDATE table1 SET old_id = id;
DO
$do$
DECLARE
    row RECORD;
    i INTEGER;
BEGIN
  i := greatest(
        (select max(id) from sch.table1),
        (select max(id) from sch.table2)) + 1;
  FOR row IN
    SELECT t1.old_id, t1.name FROM sch.table1 AS t1 ORDER BY ...
    -- if you still need the join here it should use t1.old_id instead of t1.id
  LOOP
    UPDATE sch.table1 SET id = i WHERE id = row.old_id;
    i := i + 1;
  END LOOP;
END
$do$;
ALTER TABLE table1 DROP COLUMN old_id;
```

Comment: I got rid of the join in my the query I loop and no longer ran into that problem. Thank you.